# How to use fields from other records correctly in F#?

Tags: f#, records, multiple-records

I am currently studying F#, but I am a bit struggling on using records and using their fields. I'd like to use fields from an other record.

Let's say I want to define a Person-record and a Birthday-record.

#### My code

```
type DateOfBirth =
{
    Day: int;
    Month: int;
    Year: int;
}

type Person = 
{
    Name: string;
    Birthday: DateOfBirth;
}
```

I defined my both records without any errors. Now, I am trying to create an actual instance of a person, but I am getting an error on the following code on line (Birthday.Day = 15;).

```
let John = 
{
    Name = "John";
    Birthday.Day = 15;
    Birthday.Month = 15;
    Birthday.Year = 15;
}
```

The error message that shows up is saying:
"The namespace or module 'Birthday' is not defined".

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `let John = { Name = "John"; Birthday = { Day = 15; Month = 15; Year = 15 } }`

Comment: That is the answer I am lookin' for. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

To close up this issue I've added @ildjarn's answer below as a reference that can be accepted as an answer. The idea is that the DateOfBirth instance is specified for the Birthday property as a single unit enclosed in a separate set of curly braces nested within the outer person construction.

```
let John = 
{ 
    Name = "John"; 
    Birthday = { Day = 15; Month = 15; Year = 15 } 
}
```